# Problems with position: absolute when applying it

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create a navbar whith white bars on top of the options, but the position: absolute is not responding as I expect, even if I place it after a position: relative, the white bars are wider than the width of the options:[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfueF.png)

This is the code I'm following from the tutorial, I would appreciate your help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to achieve the same:

Instead of using the pseudo element, you can use the property `border-top` along with `padding-top` to achieve the same, if what you need is the border width to be equal with the length of the option.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top:5px solid #fff;
  padding-top:10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}
/*
nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}*/
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is another way, in-case you need the width of all borders be same. You must give a fixed width to the pseudo element, instead of `100%`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line item element is wider than your link element which means that your white bar will copy the relatively positioned line item's width.  If you look in inspector you can see this clearly.

[The width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc7GM.png)

Use the border-top property instead on your links.

```
nav a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
border-top: solid 3px #fff;
padding-top: 35px
}
nav a:hover {
color: black;
}
nav a::before {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `nav a:before` :

If you want to create it the same width as your text - substract the padding:

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

or you want to place it the same size as your li item use:

```
left: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed it.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for the 40px * 2 = 80 px of padding you have added to the `li` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*delete padding */
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: relative;  
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*add this */
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
  /*and this*/
  border-top: 5px solid white;
}

/*
nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
*/
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nav a::before pseudo-element is a child of a::before.  Pseudo-elements like ::before or ::hover are always children of the elements whose selectors preface them. You need to put the position:relative property on the rule for nav a.  Currently, you have the position:relative property on the li element, which is wider than the a element.

You'll also need to add some other property to raise the line.  I've added padding-top to solve that problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #151515;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img1.png" style="max-width: 80px; margin-top: 0px;" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INGRESAR</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```